# How to play YouTube videos in a Windows8 html/javascript app?

Tags: youtube, windows-8

How can I play YouTube videos in a Windows 8 html/javascript app? I have the clip's id and I just want to play it. Perhaps via html5's video tag?

I've tried the iframe api, but failed to get it to work. I've also made a try on the javascript api, but it failed to load javascript from anther location.

Any help on the subject would be very appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: Thanks, I have looked there, but I still find it hard to find a viable solution for a windows 8 metro app. Tried the iframe version, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You should add that information to the question, along with solutions you have tried. Otherwise the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: "failed to get it to work" -- exactly what did you try and exactly why/how did it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed a YouTube class for Windows Phone which gets the MP4 link of a YouTube movie. Maybe you can use this code and start the video app with the MP4 link or set the source of a media element (if existent in Win8)?

If there's a way to start the video app with a predefined MP4-URL I can rewrite the code for Windows 8.

http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube

**UPDATE:** I've updated the code. Now simply load the URL with this async method:

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("youtube_id");
myMediaElement.Source = url.Uri;
```

`myMediaElement` is a XAML `MediaElement` control.

Check out the whole library from the project's Subversion repository: http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com

**Update:** Sorry it's C# only, you have to port it to Javascript...

Comment: Thanks Rico! I use the vido URI with the Microsoft Player Framework to get it working.

Comment: Anders, it would be great if you share your JavaScript code with us.

While looking at Rico's code, I can see that he parses the Youtube HTML page looking for a video URI. I think this is a hack that can break if Youtube change the way the page is rendered

Comment: Yes it will break when YouTube changes the page... it happened some times :)... But YouTube has no public API to get MP4 links... Maybe Google publishes a YouTube app in the future and you can launch the app by launching `youtube://video_id`