# Embed Youtube videos in Metro style application

Tags: webview, youtube, microsoft-metro

I am writing application to show youtube videos.
In WPF on windows 7 I use WebBrowser control and it works fine. But when I use WinRT WebView control to show swf file from youtube - it doesn't work. Only clear white screen.

I use approach like that : http://blog.tedd.no/2010/06/27/embedding-youtube-in-wpf-webbrowser-control/

What shall I do to have an oppotunity to show videos in Metro Style Application?
Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491774/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-a-windows8-html-javascript-app/11506960#11506960

Answer (score 2):

try this one from the mytoolkit library: http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube

Answer (score 1):

The default youtube video player (unless the user has opted into the HTML5 preview) is a Flash video control.  Flash is not supported in the Windows Application Store ("Metro") shell version of IE, or in the WebView control.

But what you can do is request youtube to use the HTML5 video player (HTML5 video is supported by the App Store version of IE and WebView).  For example, this video does play properly for me:

```
    <WebView Source="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&amp;html5=True" />
```

So you should be able to embed a video using a webview, you just have to force the webview to use the HTML5 viewer.  This can also be done as a parameter to the embed URL: see [Force HTML5 youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845484/force-html5-youtube-video)

However, this setting only says to *prefer* the HTML5 player.  Youtube may still attempt to use the flash player on some videos, which will not work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively also play the video through "[mediaelement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)" to play youtube video, though you'd have to parse the youtube video stream first. See my W8 app "[RedditTV](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-US/app/reddittv/4a46040d-445f-40cd-8a16-9bb3cc118cea)"