# Youtube Windows Store App API

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, windows-store-apps

Is there a API available that allows you to embed Youtube videos using the metro layout? I found one thats called "toolkit" btu its for .net 3.5 and I am running on .net4.5

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On codeplex is one project YouTube class
[YoutubeClass](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube)

Look at this thread too:
[How to play YouTube videos in a Windows8 html/javascript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491774/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-a-windows8-html-javascript-app)

and here is google youtube api:>
[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)