# How to play youtube video in its embeded player in metro app

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube, microsoft-metro

I am working on a metro app. I have to play youtube video in its embeded player not in that provided by metro app.
I search in net and find that there is iframe, flash and object player .I tried to implement in my app but not succeed.
Is there any to play video or I have to use the default metro player to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [How to play YouTube videos in a Windows8 html/javascript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491774/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-a-windows8-html-javascript-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a youtube embed code in a webview element.

XAML design
place a **webview** element

XAML.cs add this code below the    *this.InitializeComponent();*

```
string htmContent = " html text here";
webview.NavigateToString(htmContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [YouTube class](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube) from the [MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube). You give it a video ID (the last part of the URL) and it gets a MP4 file from Youtube for you that you can play using the standard MediaElement.